# Not receiving correct return value from an `async` function in `then` block

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

The following function adds a document in `mongodb` using `mongoose`. The success or failure is determined by return value.

```
  async function addQuestion (description,hints,topic) {
  var q = null;
  dotenv.config();
  console.log(`adding question:`);
  console.log(`description: ${description}`);
  console.log(`hints: ${hints}`);
  console.log(`topic: ${topic}`);

  
  const Question = mongoose.model(topic, questionSchema,topic);
  
  q = Question({
      description: description,
      hints: hints,
      topic: topic
  });
  await q.save()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(`added question ${result}`);
    return result;
  })
  .catch ( (err)=>{
    console.log(`error in adding question: ${err}`);
    return null;
  });
}
```

The function is called like by `addQuestionHandler`:

```
addQuestionHandler: async function (req, res) {
  console.log(`adding question: request is ${req}`);
   

  await addQuestion(req.description, req.hints,req.topic)
  .then((question)=>{
    console.log(`added question ${question}`);
    console.log(`returning value ${question}`);
    return question;
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.log(`error in adding question: ${error}`);
  })
  }
```

I see in logs that `q.save` in `addQuestion` is successful (which should return the added `document`)

```
added question {
      description: 'description of question on area',
      hints: [ 'area hint 1', 'area hint 2' ],
      topic: 'areas',
      _id: new ObjectId("64f47a56e5b349ec88a8ca98"),
      __v: 0
    }
```

But in the `then` block of  `addQuestionHandler`, I see trace `added question undefined`. why?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You are mixing promise chaining with async-await syntax.
- You haven't returned the result of `q.save()` from the `addQuestion` function.

The `addQuestion` function can be rewritten without the above-mention  problems as shown below:

```js
async function addQuestion(description, hints, topic) {
  ...
  try {
    const result = await q.save();
    console.log(`added question ${result}`);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error in adding question: ${err}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

When you don't return any value from an `async` function, the promise it returns is fulfilled with the value of `undefined` and that is why you see `undefined` in the following statement:

```
"added question undefined"
```

**Note:**

You could get rid of the `try-catch` block in the `addQuestion` function and let the calling code handle the error.

Also note that returning `null` from the `catch` block will fulfil the promise returned by the `addQuestion` function. Unless that is what you want, you should throw the error so that the returned promise is rejected and the calling code can handle the promise rejection.

But then, if all you do inside the `catch` block is throw the error, you can just omit the `try-catch` block because if `await q.save()` results in a promise rejection, promise returned by the `addQuestion` will automatically get rejected and calling code can handle that rejection.

---

Following version of `addQuestion` function uses promise chaining instead of async-await syntax to achieve the same result:

```js
function addQuestion(description, hints, topic) {
  ...
  
  return q
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(`added question ${result}`);
      return result;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`error in adding question: ${err}`);
      return null;
    });
}
```

Unless you know what you are doing, you shouldn't mix async-await syntax with promise chaining. Use either one of them but do not mix them.

Same tips apply to the above code as mentioned for the async-await version of the `addQuestion` function. You could either omit the `catch` method call or throw the error inside its callback function instead of returning `null` to avoid implicit conversion of promise rejection into promise fulfilment.

---

Calling function (`addQuestionHandler`) can also be rewritten as shown below:

```js
addQuestionHandler: async function (req, res) {
  console.log(`adding question: request is ${req}`);

  try {
    const question = await addQuestion(req.description, req.hints, req.topic);
    console.log(`added question ${question}`);
    console.log(`returning value ${question}`);
    return question;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error in adding question: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In your code, why haven't you made `addQuestion` `async`? Can you still use `await` when calling `addQuestion`?

Comment: `async` keyword is needed only if you want to use the `await` keyword _inside_ that function. The first version of `addQuestion` is `async` because I have used `await` inside it to wait for the promise returned by `q.save()`. However, the second version of `addQuestion` function that uses promise chaining, it doesn't need to be `async` function because I haven't used `await` keyword inside it. Instead, I used promise chaining. Only the function that uses the `await` keyword inside its body needs to be `async`.

Comment: without `await` and with only `promise` chaining, will `q.save` wait till the result of save is returned? I don't want that the execution goes back to `addQuestionHandler` before `save` finishes.

Comment: Yes. The execution will be as you expect it to be. See how I have written the `addQuestionHandler`. You can use that with async-await version of `addQuestion` or the second version that uses promise chaining.